# RDP thru SSH Tunnel

Tags: 16.04, ssh

On Windows, I have enjoyed RDP thru SSH (putty) Tunnels and would like to reproduce this capability from Ubuntu.  Is there an app that does this so that the Tunnel capability is a configurable RDP option?   Is there a better technique?

For the purpose of this conversation, RDP and VNC are mutually exclusive and I would like to avoid discussion of VNC.  The exception would be where an app supports both protocols.

The target LAN network has an SSH server.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal to create the tunnel

```
ssh -L 3389:$WindowsMachineLanIp:3389 user@$SshLanServer -N
```

Then use rdesktop to connect to it

```
rdesktop -g 1280x600 127.0.0.1:3389 -r \
disk:mydisk=/Path/To/LocalDirToMountOnRemoteWindowsMachine/ -r \
clipboard:CLIPBOARD \
-u $WindowsUser
```

That will connect you as $WindowsUser, with a screen resolution of 1280x600, it will mount your local folder as a disk on the windows machine and you will be able to share the clipboard (after login)